# Verifying complexity of sorting N integers, M at a time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

I am asking complexity only of the first part(sort part) of a bigger problem called external sort. 
N - number of integers (big enof to fit in memory)
M - number of integers that can be sorted in memory using merge sort.

Complexity of merge sort:
O (M log M)

But we need to sort total of N elements.
Thus, we need so sort N / M times totally.
thus

O ((N / M) * M log M)

thus finally deriving

O (N log M)

Is this correct complexity ? If not do correct my calculations.

Comment: It's correct. Since you're dealing integers, you could however use a more efficient integer sorting algorithm like Radix sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct complexity for the first stage of sorting N integers M at a time. You could express the same number differently if you say that the number of M-sized sets is k. Then you could say it's

```
O(N*Log(N/k))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end up with all N elements being sorted this is insufficient. You split your total set of N numbers into N/M subsets of M numbers each.  Then you sort each subset. As you correctly found out, this has a complexity of O(N log M), and if your goal is to end up with a couple of sorted subsets you are done and everything is fine.  However, at this point you don't have the entire set of N sorted, you just have a couple of sorted subsets and still some work to do.  What's still missing is the operation of merging those subsets together.  Assuming your merge operations always merge two subsets into one, you still have Log2( N/M ) merge operations to do, each with a complexity O(N).  So the final complexity is O(N log M + N Log(N/M) ) = O( N Log N ).  As it's supposed to be.

Comment: Quote from OP: "I am asking complexity only of the **first part** (sort part) of a bigger problem called external sort" Emphasis mine. What you describe would probably be regarded "the merge part" or something.